# Insert multiple TDs into middle of Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with 2-4 columns and 9 rows. Some of the very right columns have a text (abc), some have an image, some have both and some may have neither of them.

I want to copy the contents of the 2nd column into 3 newly created columns, but insert them in the middle (before `abc` and the image, if applicable). So that it looks like that:

[image]

This approach:

```
$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=2]").each(function(i) {
  var $newCell = $(this).wrap('<td></td>').parent();
  var $newRow = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").eq(i).parents('tr');
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  if ($newRow.find("td:contains('abc')").index() > -1) {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('abc')").before($newCell);
  } else if ($newRow.find("td.img").index() > -1) {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('img')").before($newCell);
  } else {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('img')").before($newCell);
  }
});

$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=3]").each(function(i) {
  var $newCell = $(this).wrap('<td></td>').parent();
  var $newRow = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").eq(i).parents('tr');
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  if ($newRow.find("td:contains('abc')").index() > -1) {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('abc')").before($newCell);
  } else if ($newRow.find("td.img").index() > -1) {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('img')").before($newCell);
  } else {
    $newRow.find("td:contains('img')").before($newCell);
  }
});
```

Produces the following result:

[image]

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/otv15ej0/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you can loop over each third row using `:nth-child`, appending the required `td` from each to the first row in the set. From there you can `remove()` the unneeded rows, something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('table tr').length / 3; i++) {
    var $rows = $('table tr:nth-child(3n+' + i + ')');
    $rows.not(':first').addClass('remove').find('td:eq(1)').insertAfter($rows.first().find('td:eq(1)'));
}
$('table .remove').remove();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bLu8z2kn/)

Comment: Thank you. Is is also possible, to distinguish the rows by their suffixes:|1, |2, |3, instead of looping over every 3rd row?

Comment: Yes that would be possible too, although would make the code more complex.

Comment: Something like `$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=2]")` and `$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=3]")`? In my real-life-example I need to rely on the suffixes, as there are more rows (without suffixes), which should not be looped over.

Comment: I see. In that case please add an example of your real life HTML to the question - or even start a new question as that's a fairly significant change to the logic.

Comment: Ok, I accepted your answer, because it works in that very case. I also created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37721632/insert-multiple-tds-by-suffix-into-middle-of-table